# JQuery: Change the value of hidden input in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would appreciate if you could please help me to resolve the issue described below. I haven seen and I have had similar problem to this, but haven't found any solution.

The thing I'm trying to do is to change the `value` inside the hidden `<input>` field before the form will send the data to the server that will assign new user to a certain list. The idea is that we are using one form on different pages that on submit will change the `value` inside the `<input>` field corresponding to the clicked element(classes of elements that triggering popups).

```html
<input type="hidden" name="g" id="hidden_field" value="SOME_VALUE_HERE">
```

**JS/JQ: Replacing Value in Input**

```js
var currentClass = null;    

// Classes of elements that triggering popups
$( ".popup-pop, .link-product-tab, .popup-footer, .popup-adbf-page, .popup-aboutus-page, .popup-404, .popup-eco-page" ).delay( 0 ).click(function() {
    KlaviyoSubscribe.attachToModalForm('#subscription_form', {
        ignore_cookie:true,
        custom_success_message: true,
    });
    var calledClass = this.className; // assign class that triggered the popup to "calledClass" variable
    currentClass = calledClass; // assign "calledClass" value to global var "currentClass"
});
// $('form').keyup(function(){
$('form').submit(function(){
    switch(currentClass) {   // taking currentClass to find correct value for input field
        case 'popup-pop': $("#hidden_field input").val("jeN5s3"); break; // changing value of hidden input field in correspondence to triggered popup 
        case 'link-product-tab': $("#hidden_field input").val("jeN5s3"); break;
        case 'popup-footer': $("#hidden_field").val("v4pSbe"); break;
        case 'popup-adbf-page': $("#hidden_field").val("DmCgw3"); break;    
        case 'popup-eco-page': $("#hidden_field").val("y2Z9Ly"); break;         
        case 'popup-aboutus-page': $("#hidden_field").val("t26heU"); break;
        case 'popup-404': $("#hidden_field").val("jeN5s3"); break;
    }    
});

$('form').submit(function(){ 
    $(".klaviyo_modal").fadeOut();
    window.open("https://example.com/thank-you");
});
```

**HTML: Form**

```html
<form action="//manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/subscribe" method="POST" id="subscription_form" novalidate="novalidate" class="klaviyo_subscription_form">
<input type="hidden" name="g" id="hidden_field" value="SOME_VALUE_HERE">
<div class="klaviyo_fieldset">
    <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
       <label for="klaviyo_form_first_name">First Name:</label>
       <input id="klaviyo_form_first_name" class="upform" type="text" name="first_name" value="" required/>
       <label for="subscription_form_$email">Email Address</label>
       <input type="email" class="upform" id="subscription_form_$email" name="email" required>
       </div>
    </div>
       <div class="klaviyo_fine_print"></div>
    <div class="klaviyo_form_actions">
    <input type="submit" id="subscription_form" data-dismiss="modal" class="submit_button" onclick="closeWindow()" value="I'm in! >>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="klaviyo_below_submit"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Why have you added **.delay(0)** to your popup click handler?

Comment: @RamblinRose testing purposes

Comment: @MartinShishkov regarding this - no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still i don't know the reason why it was not working (script was correct...). I've rewrite the script by changing  ( **'** ) to ( **"** ):

What is this script for?
This script assigns a certain popup that was called by clicking on a text/button/img with a certain class (ex. `.popup-footer`) to a certain list in [Klaviyo](https://www.klaviyo.com/).
Purpose?
To track from what subscription form (i.e. popup) customer came; separate lists will help to run special campaigns.
*there is an option in klaviyo to add a custom properties such $source_page, $time etc., but in our case another solution required - as we did using this script*

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
 switch(currentClass){
 case "popup-pop": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("jeN5s3");break;
 case "link-product-tab": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("jeN5s3");break;
 case "popup-footer": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("z62byt");break;
 case "popup-adbf-page": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("DmCgw3");break;
 case "popup-eco-page": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("y2Z9Ly");break;
 case "popup-aboutus-page": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("t26heU");break;
 case "popup-404": $("input#klaviyo_input").val("jeN5s3");break;
    default: console.log("Unknown class " + currentClass);
}
$(".klaviyo_modal").fadeOut();
 window.open("https://example.com/thank-you");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be wrong:

```
$("#hidden_field input")
```

The selector above means "any input inside an element with ID `#hidden_field`". It doesn't look like that's what you're looking for from your HTML code, though.

`#hidden_field` is already your input. Change:

```
$("#hidden_field input")
```

into:

```
$("#hidden_field")
```

or:

```
$("input#hidden_field")
```

Change every occurence, and it should work.

Comment: That is my bad, I've put wrong example. 
But even like that it is only working for two cases "404-page" and "popup-footer". And i have no idea why it is not changing the value inside the input.

Comment: @AlexCross You still have the wrong selector for `popup-pop` and `link-product-tab`.

Comment: @Barmar `console.log(currentClass)` shows `null`, but if i'll do `alert(currentClass)` it will show me the active class

Comment: That makes no sense. You put them at the same place in the program?

Comment: Why put a wrong example, how are we supposed to help you out!?

Comment: @Alex Cross: It's not.

Comment: @nbrogi I've put an example of my code, change it to the working one (not 100% working, but still working) and i'm asking for help, because i haven't seen anything like this on stackoverflow and the origin of the issue is not clear to me. This example might contain errors  - this is the reason why i'm asking for help. Why would i ask if it works perfectly?

Comment: @nbrogi it is strange, i've found in console that the defaultValue is one of the *cases* - y2Z9Ly. 
It is changing the value to the correct one, but somehow this data is missing on server side... or it might be something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the class/click elements which assign *currentClass* have more than one class this code

```
 var calledClass = this.className;
```

will return **all** classes assigned the element, not just the one you're interested in.  Add a default case in your switch to catch this potential problem.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    switch(currentClass) {   // taking currentClass to find correct value for input field
        case 'popup-pop': $("#hidden_field input").val("jeN5s3"); break; // changing value of hidden input field in correspondence to triggered popup 
        case 'link-product-tab': $("#hidden_field input").val("jeN5s3"); break;
        case 'popup-footer': $("#hidden_field").val("v4pSbe"); break;
        case 'popup-adbf-page': $("#hidden_field").val("DmCgw3"); break;    
        case 'popup-eco-page': $("#hidden_field").val("y2Z9Ly"); break;         
        case 'popup-aboutus-page': $("#hidden_field").val("t26heU"); break;
        case 'popup-404': $("#hidden_field").val("jeN5s3"); break;
// handle the case where currentClass is not considered
        default: console.log("Unknown class " + currentClass);
    }    
});
```

Comment: I've tried to solve it another way, by clearing all classes and leaving the only one (even though this elements have only one class)
`$('.' + classes.join(',.')).click(function(){
        var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
        cls = $.grep(classNames, function(c, i) {
            return $.inArray(c, classes) !== -1;
        })[0];
    cls = '.' + cls; 
    KlaviyoSubscribe.attachToModalForm('#popup', {
        ignore_cookie:true,
        custom_success_message: true,
        extra_properties: { {{ page.title}} }
    });
});`

Comment: I've tried this and console log is empty... no errors